# Firebase Cloud Messaging Send HTTP-Post in Java

Tags: java, apache, http, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to create a **Java Application** which should send a **Protocol** to the **Firebase Cloud Messaging** Servers. **Now I have the problem, that I don't know how to see if my message was sent correctly**. When I head to the **Web-Console** of **Firebase/Notifications** there is **no message** to see.

My Code (just in case):

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Mainclass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declaration of Message Parameters
    String message_url = new String("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    String message_sender_id = new String("XXXX-XXXX");
    String message_key = new String("key=XXXX-XXXX");

    // Generating a JSONObject for the content of the message
    JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
    message.put("message", "TEXT");
    JSONObject protocol = new JSONObject();
    protocol.put("to", message_sender_id);
    protocol.put("data", message);

    // Send Protocol
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(message_url);
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.addHeader("Authorization", message_key);

        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(protocol.toString());
        request.setEntity(params);
        System.out.println(params);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
[Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1,Content-Length: 59,Chunked: false]


HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, Date: Mon, 26 Dec 2016 12:09:13 GMT, Expires: Mon, 26 Dec 2016 12:09:13 GMT, Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Server: GSE, Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="35,34", Transfer-Encoding: chunked] org.apache.http.client.entity.DecompressingEntity@32cf48b7}
```

Thank you!

PS There is a reference of FCM https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server

Comment: Hey I am also trying the same thing. Getting same responce as you.So now I am trying a different way to send it.If it succeeds i get success:1 kind of message. .. then i reply back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "*how to see if my message was sent correctly*", I'm presuming you mean if it was sent towards the client app device.

For this scenario, you can make use of the [Delivery Receipts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#ccs). However, you'll have to implement an [XMPP server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref), instead of the regular HTTP connection server.

One way to also have check is to make use of the [Diagnostics tool](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en), but a requirement for this to be available is for your app to be at least in Alpha Testing.

---

The only logs/details you can see in the Firebase Console are the messages sent using Firebase Console itself, it won't show any messages sent using the FCM REST API.

---

Else, if you are pertaining to just verify if the message was sent correctly towards the FCM servers, then you should check the [response](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#http_response). Normally, it should return `"success": 1` and a `message_id`.